# How to change menu alignment on large screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I change the alignment of a dropdown menu to right only on large screens?

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Right-aligned menu
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, `dropdown-menu-right` should be applyed only on large screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsedlr's answer put me on the right track.

`dropdown-menu-right` class is defined by bootstrap as:

```
.dropdown-menu-right{
    right:0;
    left:auto;
}
```

To avoid conflicts, I defined a new class `dropdown-menu-right-lg` copied from bootstrap and i have applied the desired media query:

```
@media (min-width: 998px) {
    .dropdown-menu-right-lg{
        right:0;
        left:auto;
    }
}

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Right-aligned menu
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right-lg">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@media` in your `CSS`

```css
@media (min-width: 998px) {
    .dropdown-menu-right {
        /* css here */
    }
}
```

Of course, `998px` can be replaced with any value that suites your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var width=600;
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(this).outerWidth()<width){
            $('div.dropdown-menu').removeClass('dropdown-menu-right');
        }else{
            $('div.dropdown-menu').addClass('dropdown-menu-right');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="btn-group ml-lg-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Right-aligned menu
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu mr-lg-auto">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `ml-lg-auto` on the parent `div` of that dropdown `button`. It will align your button right on large devices only. If you want the same for medium devices simply use `ml-md-auto`, it'll keep your button right both on large and medium devices.

Hope this solution will make your work easier